# "or" conditional in Python

Tags: python, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I want to check if a value is -1 or less than another value.

In order to do that, I've done the following:

```
def isValidWord(word, hand, wordList):
    """
    Returns True if word is in the wordList and is entirely
    composed of letters in the hand. Otherwise, returns False.

    Does not mutate hand or wordList.

    word: string
    hand: dictionary (string -> int)
    wordList: list of lowercase strings
    """
    if word not in wordList:
        return False
    for k, v in getFrequencyDict(word).items():
        if hand.get(k, -1) < v or hand.get(k, -1) == -1:
            return False
    return True
```

**To note:** `getFrequencyDict(word)` returns a dictionary of the letters word with the frequency of the letters.

**The question that remains is:** am I committing a mistake in the following line?

```
if hand.get(k, -1) < v or hand.get(k, -1) == -1:
```

Comment: Isn't `-1 < v`? Just `hand.get(k, -1) < v` should work.

Comment: Do you want to check that `hand.get(k, -1)` is less than a value or greater? Your explanation doesn't match your code.

Comment: @internet_user I like the way you solved OP XY problem.

Comment: That's me overthinking everything again. Sometimes you just need someone else to point out the obvious :L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that all the values in the dict are positive, the checking

```
if hand.get(k, -1) < v:
```

will be enough.

In a more generic case, this seems like a proper way to use `or` (your code makes it clear that you check for something, **or** for the default).

Answer (score 0):

Using `-1` as default seems superfluous here and will not allow to generalize to the case where `hand` contains negative values.

```
if hand.get(k) is None or hand.get(k) < v:
    ...
```

Or alternatively, even `get` can be considered superfluous. For checking a key exists you can simply use `in`.

```
if k not in hand or hand[k] < v:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use **set**. **Dictionary** is not needed for this.
**Set** supports difference operation.

```
def isValidWord(word, hand, wordList):
    """
    Returns True if word is in the wordList and is entirely
    composed of letters in the hand. Otherwise, returns False.

    Does not mutate hand or wordList.

    word: string
    hand: set of letters
          eg: set(["u", "s", "a"] or set("usa")
    wordList: set of strings
          eg: set(["zeus", "osiris", "thor"])
    """
    if word not in wordList:
        return False
    if len(set(word) - hand) != 0:
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: In this case could we just 'return (word in wordList and (len(set(word) - hand) == 0))'?

Answer (score -2):

```
if any(c in someList for c in ("a", "á", "à", "ã", "â"))
```

This can be written in the given way above.(note it isn't exactly the same for your Question, just the idea)